# Any android devices on the market with a perfectly square display?

Tags: screen, hardware, external-display

Are there any android based devices on the market with a perfectly square display? If not is there any particular reason why not and would it create any problems when switching between portrait and landscape modes?

Comment: Screens are created by a few large manufacturers and the common display glasses they provide are not square. The closest what you can get is a 4:3 screen.

Comment: Welcome to SR! Please note that hHardware/shopping questions are off-topic here, see e.g. [Are questions about what hardware is available on topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/are-questions-about-what-hardware-is-available-on-topic) and [Can I ask questions regarding suggesting Android phones with specifications that I mention?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/can-i-ask-questions-regarding-suggesting-android-phones-with-specifications-that)